# How to output phrase n times in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

How can I do the equivalent of the below code in sinatra? - Output a phrase to a webpage n times?

```
get "/say/:number/:phrase" do
  params[:number].to_i.times do
    puts params[:phrase]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sinatra, the return value is what is returned to the browser. Since you're using `puts`, it's just printing to the console and `times` returns the value, not the block results. The easiest way to simply return `phrase` `number` times is something like this:

```
get "/say/:number/:phrase" do 
  phrase * number.to_i
end
```

If you want to do extra processing to the phrase (`upcase` for example), you can build it in a string.

```
get "/say/:number/:phrase" do 
  result = ""
  number.to_i.times do |i|
    result += phrase.upcase
  end
  result
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Re `puts`: my code was just an example of what I want, I know I can't `puts` to the webpage :).